# Can a linear mixed model (LMM) be superior to a linear model (LM) in case of a single repeated measure (paired sample)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, lm

### In short and in general terms:

While LMMs are often used in longitudinal studies with multiple repeated measures, I never came across an example which models a paired design. However, I also never read one should not use a LMM in case of a paired design. Thus, I am wondering if a LMM might make sense in case of paired design.

### My specific case:

I performed an experiment with a counterbalanced design. Thus 2 groups with 10 subjects each and two measurements: one with and one without treatment in reverse order. I am interested in the effect of the treatment on two dependent variables. Besides the independent variable of the treatment, I am also analyzing extraneous variables and their effect on the two dependent variables.

For both models the LMM formula would be as follows:

```
Vd ~ Vtreat + Vextra1 + ... + Vextrak + (1 | subject)
```

When comparing LM and LMM for the **first** dependent variable I get:

- `exactRLRT(LMM)` does not support the use of a random effect (`p-value = 0.5016`)
- AICc smaller for LM (`delta = 2.5`)
- `anova.lme(LMM, LM)` gives `p-value = 0.4596`

And for the models of the **second** dependent variable:

- `exactRLRT(LMM)` supports the use of a random effect (`p-value = 5e-04`)
- AICc smaller for LMM (`delta = 8.2`)
- `anova.lme(LMM, LM)` gives (`p-value = 0.0013`)

Thus, I would use a LM for dependent variable 1 and a LMM for the dependent variable 2. Would that be an appropriate solution or am I missing anything fundamentally?

### Another specific concern:

Can I compare LM and LMM by means of AICc (LMM fitted via `ML`)? Is it also a valid comparison given a different fixed effect structure? Such as:

```
LM:  Vd ~ Vtreat + Vextra1 + (1 | subject)
LMM: Vd ~ Vtreat
```